# How to send commands to create 2 over Bluetooth

Tags: irobot-create

I'm very new to create 2. I want to send commands using Bluetooth. I have already bought the bluetooth USB radio. What other devices do I need to get or how can I set up sending commands over bluetooth. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Which Bluetooth dongle for the Roomba do you have?

Comment: I don't have any yet. Is RooTooth the only one available in the market?

Comment: How do you pair the rootooth? It came with no instructions and it doesn't even seem like its on?

Answer (score 2):

Once you pair your computer's Bluetooth with the dongle on the robot, it should create a virtual serial port.  Then you can talk to the Roomba over this port.  Try out the [tethered driving tutorial](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Create_2_Tethered_Driving_2.pdf), except your tether is wireless.